# While deploying on Openshift pod is coming up for my app and By looking to logs got this error ' Permission denied'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, openshift

My DockerFIle:

```
     # Builds a Docker to deliver dist/
     FROM nginx:1.11.10-alpine
     COPY dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
     RUN chmod -R 777 /var/cache/nginx
```

Error:
2019/02/20 05:28:42 [emerg] 1#1: mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)

Comment: Your image is expecting to run as ``root``, which will not happen by default on OpenShift. See https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/why-do-my-applications-run-as-a-random-user-id.html and https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-can-i-enable-an-image-to-run-as-a-set-user-id.html Unless you have cluster admin access, you will need to write your image so can run as arbitrary user ID.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton i have gone through the both documentation but still confused where to start and what to ?

Comment: Try reading https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/creating_images/guidelines.html then and pay attention to the bit about supporting arbitrary user IDs. This means building your image correctly. The other links from before were, if you were cluster admin, how you could allow your image to run as root.